# Access Subform Source object

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

What I am trying to achieve is for a combo box (Combo_sf) selection to dictate the form in the subform control (sf_record) I have about 10 forms, their names are in the combo box data. I am new to VBA and am not sure if my approach is right:

```
Private Sub Combo_sf_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strLoadTable As String  

    strLoadTable = "Form." & Me.Combo_sf.Value
    MsgBox strLoadTable

    Forms![frm_Mnu_Manage Configuration Settings]!sf_record.Form.SourceObject = strLoadTable

End Sub
```

I have placed this in the combobox's after update event but when I make my selection nothing happens in the form. Am I approaching this right or would another way work better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach *should* work. I put a combo box named `cbxSubform` on my main form and added one line of code to its `AfterUpdate()` event handler...

```
Private Sub cbxSubform_AfterUpdate()
Me.mySubform.SourceObject = Me.cbxSubform.Value
End Sub
```

...and changing the selection in the combo box switches the subforms immediately. Are you sure that the `AfterUpdate()` code for your combo box is actually firing? (You could add a `MsgBox` or a `Debug.Print` to check.)

Comment: Thank you, I think the issue lyed in my macros not been turn on, but this info was very help thank ye for all of your help !

Answer (score 4):

It could be this line which is tripping you up:

```
strLoadTable = "Form." & Me.Combo_sf.Value
```

What is your form object called? If your form is called `Form.myTableName` it could be the `.` that is throwing it out, try setting it to a form without a dot in its name.

Answer (score 4):

In this line, it seems the code attempts to change the `SourceObject` property of a `Form` object.

```vb
Forms![frm_Mnu_Manage Configuration Settings]!sf_record.Form.SourceObject = strLoadTable
```

However, `SourceObject` is a property of a subform *control*, not the form contained in that control.  So if the subform control is named *sf_record*, do it this way.

```vb
Forms![frm_Mnu_Manage Configuration Settings]!sf_record.SourceObject = strLoadTable
```

Also, if the after update procedure runs from `[frm_Mnu_Manage Configuration Settings]`, you can use `Me` to refer to the form.

```vb
Me!sf_record.SourceObject = strLoadTable
```

Finally, if `Me.Combo_sf.Value` is the name of a form, you don't need to prefix its name with *"Form."*.  It worked either way in my test, but I would just leave off *"Form."*.

```vb
strLoadTable = Me.Combo_sf.Value
```